# How do I deal with controller resource in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using the resource tool for my controller and my route but the store method appears not to work. Could you highlight what I did wrong. Is the controller name needs to be the same as the model one? I am confuse

FarmController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FarmController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('farms.index', compact('animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = new Animal();
        return view('farms.create', compact('user', 'animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        Animal::create($this->validateRequest());


        return redirect('farms.show');
    }
    private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'dateOfBirth' => 'required|date',
            'placeOfBirth' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
```

Animal.php (controller)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Animal extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }}

animals (table)

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAnimalsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('animals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->date('dateOfBirth');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('placeOfBirth');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('animals');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Add Animal')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Farm</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Welcome {{ $user->name }} Please Add an animal</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form action="{{ url('farms') }}" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dateOfBirth">Date Of Birth: </label>
                    <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                </div>
                <div class="pb-5">
                    {{ $errors->first('dateOfBirth') }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="placeOfBirth">Place Of Birth</label>
                    <input type="text" name="placeOfBirth" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="pb-5">
                    {{ $errors->first('placeOfBirth') }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                        <option value="M">Male</option>
                        <option value="F">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user">User</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="user">
                        <option value="{{ $user->id }}" name="user">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Farm</button>

                @csrf
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

web.php (routes)

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {

    // All your admin routes go here.

    Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');
});

Route::middleware('farms')->group(function () {

    // All your admin routes go here.
    Route::resource('/farms', 'FarmController');
});
```

When I am submitting the form, it seems like it just refreshes the page and do not add anything in my table. I have been stuck on this in two entire days. any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `validateRequest` function you have

```php
'user_id' => 'required',
```

But your form in the view has no field named `user_id`

The select element is named `user`

```html
<select class="form-control" name="user">
  <option value="{{ $user->id }}" name="user">{{ $user->name }}</option>
</select>
```

Change one of them so they can match, I guess that the page refresh is just failed validation

You may want to check for **any** validation error in your view to find out what's wrong as per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

For example

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just change your form action then it hit in correct mehtod. Here is the action for your form

```
{{route('farms.store')}}
```